# Evaluating $\int_\gamma \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I want to evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}dz$ if $\gamma = \alpha + \beta$, where $\alpha(t)=te^{it}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 4\pi$ and $\beta$ is a parametrization of the line segment joining $4 \pi$ and $0$.

I did the graph of $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

[image]

So $\gamma$ is a closed curve.

First, I tried to use the Cauchy's Theorem with $f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}$, but the conditions $\lim_{z \to -1} (z+1)f(z)=0$ and $\lim_{z \to -4} (z+4)f(z)=0$ are not satisfied.

Then, I tried to decomopose $\frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}$ into partial fractions $\frac{A}{z+1}+\frac{B}{z+4}$ to separate the integral into two integrals to use Cauchy's integral formula for each integral, but I failed to find $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Have you tried integrating along $\alpha$ then adding the result to integrating along $\beta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

You had the right idea to use partial fraction expansion.  So, note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)(z+4)}&=1-\frac{5z+3}{(z+1)(z+4)}\\\\
&=1+\frac{2/3}{z+1}-\frac{17/3}{z+4}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes :D Nice trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Twink It's worth mentioning that
$$\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz \neq
2 \pi i \left( \operatorname* {Res}_{z = -1} f(z) +
 \operatorname* {Res}_{z = -4} f(z) \right).$$

Comment: @maxim I hope that you're doing well and staying safe and healthy.  The contour integral can be broken into two pieces.  The first begins on $\alpha$ from $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$ and closes along $\beta$ from $2\pi$ to $0$.  The second begins on $\alpha$ from $2\pi$ to $4\pi$ and closes from $4\pi$ to $2\pi$.  The first encloses only the pole at $-1$,  but not the one at $-4$.  The other part encloses both poles.

Comment: Exactly, that was probably the point of the question, that the residues have to be multiplied by the winding numbers.